# how to set char array to string in c

Tags: c, operating-system

so i have a struct call  Process_Info

```
  struct Process_Info {
    char name[128];
    int pid;
    int parent_pid;
    int priority;
    int status;
      };
```

and an array of Process_Info call info. I set pid in info to an integer, it works but when I try to set name in info to "{kernel}" like this

```
info[i].name="{kernel}";
```

and it give me incompatible type in assignment error. I search online it seem i can do this, like in http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/string/array-vs-ptr/, they did char label[] = "Single"; So what am i doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Initialize char array from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963911/how-to-initialize-char-array-from-a-string)

Comment: Unfotunately, what you can do in an assignment isn't the same as what you can do in an initialization, even though they look similar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer: A C compiler will bake constant strings into the binary, so you need to use [strncpy](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strncpy.html) (or [strcpy](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/strcpy.html) if you aren't worried about security) to copy "{kernel}" into `info[i].name`.

The longer answer: Whenever you write

```
char label[] = "Single";
```

the C compiler will bake the string "Single" into the binary it produces, and make `label` into a pointer to that string.  In C language terms, "Single" is of type `const char *` and thus cannot be changed in any way.  However, you cannot assign a `const char *` to a `char *`, since a `char *` *can* be modified.

In other words, you cannot write

```
char label[] = "Single";
label[0] = "T";
```

because the compiler won't allow the second line.  However, you *can* change `info[i].name` by writing something like

```
info[i].name[0] = '[';
```

because `info[i].name` if of type `char *`.  To solve this problem, you should use `strncpy` (I referenced a manual page above) to copy the string "{Kernel}" into `info[i].name` as

```
strncpy(info[i].name, "{Kernel}", 256);
info[i].name[255] = '\0';
```

which will ensure that you don't overflow the buffer.

Comment: Correct. The reason the linked sample code works is because they're initializing the value at the time of declaration.

Comment: Not very accurate. In you first example, `label` is an array, not a string, and it's certainly possible to modify it. C allows initializing an array by a literal string, but doesn't allow assigning it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be mistaken.  The way you would assign this would be one char at a time like so...

```
name[] = {'a','b','c','d'};
```