# How to use struct pointer to set char name?

Tags: c

```
struct player {
    char name[20];
    struct player *next;
};

int main() {
  struct player *p;
  p.name = "bob";
}
```

error: request for member 'name' in something not a structure or union

How would I set a char name with a struct?

Comment: `strcpy()` or something else

Comment: You are just initializing a pointer and _not_ allocating memory for it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set char array to string in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322607/how-to-set-char-array-to-string-in-c)

Comment: read a C book...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that little piece of code you have *multiple* problems.

The first, about the error you get, you should have been told by just about any book or tutorial, good or bad. You need to use the "arrow" operator `->`, as in `p->name`.

But then you would get another error, because you can't assign to an array, only [*copy*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) to it.

And when that's done, you still have one more error, and that is your use of an uninitialized pointer. Uninitialized local variables (which is what `p`) is are really uninitialized. Their values will be *indeterminate* and seemingly random. Attempting to dereference (what you do with `->`) such a pointer will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In short, I recommend you to go back to your text book, and start over from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix is to not declare `p` as a pointer to a struct, but rather an actual struct....and then use `strcpy()` to set `name`.  `C` doesn't use `=` for string assignment like some other programming languages.

```
struct player {
    char name[20];
    struct player *next;
};

int main() {
  struct player p;
  strcpy(p.name, "bob");
}
```