# How can I assign a String to char array that resides in a struct in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

Here is my code which I would expect it to compile, but it does not:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct turtle {
    char name[20];
    int age;
} turtle;

int main(){

    turtle koray = {"koray",25};
    turtle halim;

    halim.name = "halim"; // This line will cause in compile error.
    halim.age = 25;

    printf("%s\n",koray.name);
    printf("%s\n",halim.name);

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

This complies successfully, but prints garbage:

```
*(halim.name) = "halim";
```

by garbage I mean:

```
koray
p
```

Comment: Doesn't the compiler warn in anger for this `halim.name = "halim";`?

Comment: It should tell you ... - read the warning.

Comment: @alk It says: array type 'char [20]' is not assignable but I do not understand why..

Comment: Just because arrays in C are not assignable. It's made this way.

Comment: @KorayTugay.: My answer was correct but I have unnecessarily used the terms like "deep copy" or "shallow copy". These are the concepts in c++. If interested you can find it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy  Sorry for inconvenience. I have removed my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can figure out by reading the error message.

```
error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘const char [6]’ to ‘char [20]’
```

`"halim"` is a `const char [6]` and `name` is a `char [20]`, and they [cannot be assigned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/965851/2842375) directly.

Use [`strcpy()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm) instead.

```
strcpy(halim.name,"halim");
```

Comment: ah I see.. My compiler is not exact as yours I guess. It only says: ../hello.c:14:13: error: array type 'char [20]' is not assignable
 and it was confusing.. Thanks..

Comment: @KorayTugay That warning is also OK. Arrays aren't assignable, even if the types (which include the lengths) match. I would say your compiler warning is actually less misleading than the one in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

In C array cannot be assigned. (They can be initialised on definition however).

To fill a C-"string" use [`strcpy()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html):

```
strcpy(halim.name, "halim");
```